# Displaying incorrect error message when voting on own posts on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, error-message, popups

Please see the below image:

> [image]

As you can see, I am voting on my own question having 3 upvotes. The question's score displayed as 4 instead of 3 for two seconds and then displayed a box saying "An error has occured - please retry your request" instead of not allowing the user to upvote on his question by displaying "You can't vote your own post". Why is this happening? I verified in other SE sites, those are working fine.

Comment: The vote did not count, it should have reverted on your screen when the error message popped up, at least it does so for me. As for the wrong error message - the correct one probably got misplaced somewhere. The "error" you're looking for is that you can't vote on your own post, it's just not displaying the correct message.

Comment: Yes. vote did not count. Thats what i am asking about that error. Is this the bug for MS only?

Comment: It appears to only be affecting Meta right now. Meta is sometimes used for new features and changes that haven't been pushed network-wide yet, but I couldn't tell you what exactly is causing the error message to fail like that.

Comment: Well, the response from the server is the same in both places: `{"Success":false,"Warning":false,"NewScore":1,"Message":"You can't vote for your own post.","Refresh":false}` so it means the JavaScript code handling that response here on Meta went funky. Let's hope the developer doing it will notice the bug (or this post :)) before going live network wide. :)

Comment: Also worth to mention this generic error happens when voting on deleted posts here on Meta..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was caused by a js typo (`message` vs `Message`!) and is fixed now. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Today i observed that the UI properties of Alert dialogs are changed. Those are looking good but in the before usecase i need to click the alert dialog again to dismiss but now, i have to click wrong button in alert dialog. I think this is not fine as before functionality. Actually, "Click dialog box again to dismiss" is the best option.. What u say???

Comment: Any chance this same typo still exists [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168438/152859)? :)