# Unable to load pop up in review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close, error-message

When I open the Close-popup in the review queues for a single question multiple times I get a red box with "Unable to load popup - Please try again".

Steps to reproduce:

1. go to review queue.
2. go to Close Votes.
3. press Close button -> popup opens
4. close Popup by "x" or Esc
5. press Close button -> red box with message displays

For me it seems there is a timing issue, that when I click too fast again on the "Close" button, when I just closed the popup, the red box displays.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy, the proper error message (which we're sending down but not using for... some reason) will be displayed.

Comment: The message "Unable to load popup - Please try again" still shows when i flag a question or answer using the steps above. Will this also be fixed or should i open a new question?

Comment: @Jehof probably a related problem, I'll take a look after lunch.

Comment: @Jehof yep, sort of the same thing.  Fix for the flag link will go out with the next build.

Comment: The popup "My Logins" in the profile still shows the message. Also is the popup not draggable.

Answer (score 4):

Yup that's indeed timing issue, the response from the server when it fails is:

> You may only load the close dialog every 3 seconds.

And the status code is "409 Conflict".

The bug is that the actual message isn't showing properly but instead it show generic message.

Similar issue was reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167209/152859), hopefully it's the same small typo. :)