# Close button creating multiple loading animation icons with http 409

Tags: bug, close-dialog

I was working on the [script burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406928/the-script-tag-is-being-burninated/420832#420832) and doing systematic editing / voting / commenting / closing. At one point, I clicked on the close-vote button, and got a loading animation icon. It didn't  go away for ~3 seconds, so I did what any monkey would do and clicked it again. It gave me another loading animation icon. My monkey brain was very amused so I decided to click it three more times.

[image: multiple loading animations]

Both the non-monkey brain and monkey brain decided to collaborate to get a screenshot for separate reasons. I'm happy to say the screenshot was gotten before the bug flew away. The close-vote popup appeared after ~10 or fewer seconds, and the multiple loading animation icons all went away.

In my browser console, I see this message for each time I clicked:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 ()

I tried to reproduce the issue by rapidly clicking on the close button, but I instead got the expected behaviour of having the cooldown notification pop up at the top of my page. I don't remember any particular weird conditions that were in place when this happened.

Possibly related: [Unable to load pop up in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168438/997587). This post also mentions http 409, and the bug was related to the cooldown for opening the popup. I'm pretty sure I didn't open the close-vote dialog within that cooldown, but my memory is fuzzy. Sorry I don't know for sure if it was due to the cooldown.

Update: Here are some more screenshots I got today in a review queue where this time instead of the loading icons just vanishing, I got a bunch of popups:
["you can only load every 3 seconds"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P65Jx.png)
["unable to load popup; please try again"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xanej.png)
[a bunch of popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Mfl.png)

Comment: This was probably just a transitory networking server loading issue (or JS running slow on your machine). The initial request obviously took a long time to return a response. The 409 response is likely a red herring. SE servers *normally* provide a 409 response when you make a specific request type more than once too rapidly (i.e. faster than the defined rate limit for those requests). For example, a 409 response is sent when you click on the close-vote button to open the dialog more than once every 3 seconds. You said that's what you did, so one or more 409 responses is *normal*.

Comment: @Makyen If that's the case, maybe the solution woul be to disable the button/input while the response is still in-flight? And then re-enable it once the reponse has arrived.